# Servers with 24 NVMe drives - read throughput

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

We would like to buy some servers and we are looking into DELL server with 24 NVMe drives (like R740xd2 - 2 socket server) since we need very high read IOPS and throughput. We are however wondering what's the maximal throughput we can achieve with this solution. AFAIK, each NVMe *takes* 4 PCIe lanes but I am not able to find what's the number of available lanes on these servers. Usually NVMe drives offer around 24 Gbps but I know it is not real that 24 NVMe drives would give us 24 * 24 Gbps in parallel read.

So the question is, what is the throughput we can expect out of server like this while doing parallel read from all drives? I know that we'll probably reach the limit of what CPU can do but I am just wondering what is achievable. Anything around 48 Gbps would be win.

Comment: This is a question for sales if you dont already own the gear.  If you do, benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a study done using IOMeter to test the disk performance on a Dell 740xd, however it was using 12 NVME SSD's and not 24.

https://www.principledtechnologies.com/Dell/PowerEdge_R740xd_SSD_performance_0717.pdf

A simulated OLTP workload achieved 12.8 GBps and 1,597,000 IOPS, while a media streaming workload resulted in 38.4 GBps and 600,000 IOPS.